# UIScrollView initializing with two uiimageviews from system?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a Nib with a scrollview which i use on my controller. I have to make some constant calculations based on the scrollview.subviews count. However, surprisingly the scrollview is always starting with two uiimage views.

The scrollview at my Nib file is empty, and i have even checked the nib source code to assure there is no garbage there. I also deleted the scrollview and created another with the same result.

I am always receiving the same views there (always at, so my scrollview.subviews.count always start at 2. What could be causing this??

If I print scrollview subviews just after initializing view..

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TileScreen" owner:self options:nil];
    NSLog(@"Started scrollview with subviews %@", _scrollView.subviews);
```

I receive:

```
Started scrollview with subviews (
    "<UIImageView: 0x1dcb50; frame = (294 400; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e51b0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x1bb6a0; frame = (294 400; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1a9b50>>"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well before I posted this question I understood the problem. I wanted to share in case someone falls into this.

The problem is that the "Show horizontal scrollbar, Show vertical scrollbar" add the mentioned  UIImageViews. You can avoid this by simply unchecking the property on the IB.

If you want to show the scrollbars though, you will need to take into account these two views in your count.